# How to get rid of error "'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'"?

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I have tried setting `type` to `module` to `package.json` and that did nothing. What can I do to get rid of this error? My project is TypeScript and I'm using `import` for all my other packages without issue.

The code causing the issue:

```
import { tagify } from 'cypress-tags';

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('file:preprocessor', tagify(config));
```

The tagify code:

```
import through from 'through';
export declare const transform: (fileName: string, config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions) => through.ThroughStream;
declare const preprocessor: (config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions) => any;
export { preprocessor as tagify };
```

The full error:

```
SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
    at ProjectConfigIpc.<anonymous> (/Users/george/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.3.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/data-context/src/data/ProjectConfigManager.js:154:60)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
    at ProjectConfigIpc.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at ProjectConfigIpc.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at ProjectConfigIpc.emit (/Users/george/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.3.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/data-context/src/data/ProjectConfigIpc.js:64:22)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/george/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.3.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/data-context/src/data/ProjectConfigIpc.js:40:18)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:917:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

Comment: Can you show the traceback of your error? Thanks

Comment: @GabrielPichot Added to post.